# Несколько асинхронных апросов на один скрипт

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, pdo

Итак.

Есть таблица MYSQL типа Memory. В ней постоянно меняются некоторые числовые данные (несколько строк с числами) и эти изменения нужно отслеживать и оперативно возвращать в клиентский браузер. За это отвечает один php-скрипт. Этот же скрипт, может принимать от клиента новые значения и сохранять их в memory таблице.
То есть у php скрипта две задачи: отслеживать изменения и записывать новые, если поступят.

Отслеживание изменений в таблице происходит созданием бесконечных удерживаемых соединений (по 30 сек) к скрипту. Отправка новых значений от клиента происходит независимым запросом на тот же скрипт, с другими $_GET параметрами.

Так вот, при отправке новых данных на тот же скрипт, второй запрос просто повисает до тех пор, пока не прервется удерживаемый запрос, отслеживающий изменения данных.

Вот код, отслеживающий изменения:

```
    $finishTime = time() + intval(ini_get('max_execution_time') - 3);
    do {
        if ($db->hasNewData()) {
             // возвращаем новые данные
        }
        usleep(100000); // delay 100 msec
        echo "\n";
        flush();
    } while(time() < $finishTime && connection_status() == 0);
```

Есть догадка, что это связано с подключением к БД. Возможно что есть какая-то блокировка, которая мешает второму параллельному запросу начать свое выполнение.
Пробовал делать тестовый скрипт без подключения к бд с тем же кодом удерживания соединения и вполне себе удавалось делать 5 одновременных запросов без каких-то подвисаний.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался?

PS: пробовал и на apache+mysq и на nginx+php-fpm+mysql - везде одинаково.

Comment: Скорее всего БД не отпускает соединение. А зачем нужна задержка? Может сам скрипт запускать каждые 30 сек.

Comment: Насчет соединения с БД была единственная догадка, но если честно не очень в это верил. Верный ответ уже дали. Спасибо за коммент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть догадка, что это связано с сессиями. После использования сессию надо закрывать.

Ну или не пытаться открывать длинные скрипты из одного и того же браузера

Comment: Интересная мысль! Попробую закрывать сессию перед данным циклом.

Comment: Тысяча чертей! Вы оказались правы! Огромное вам спасибо. Кстати нашел об этом вот такой комментарий, если кому интересно http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php#110649